# Get Site ID using sharepoint web services

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

How can i get the Site ID not the web ID using the built in sharepoint web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you will find it in sSiteMetadata returned from [SiteData.GetSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms773417%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: in the Get siteUrl method there is out siteID and out siteUrl